# What are all the OS X special user folders?

Tags: macos, folders, user-account

I know OS X has a `~/Sites` folder with its own icon for keeping your websites, and it isn't there by default, you have to create it.

Are there more folders similar to this one that receive special icons after creation?

Comment: The `~/Sites` folder was removed in Mountain Lion, but nothing saying you can't add it back yourself. Reference: http://digishock.ca/os/enable-the-sites-folder-for-mountain-lion/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## <sub><sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub></sub> ~/Applications

For storing apps that you want to be private to your account, and does have a 'special icon' (the icon of /Applications) upon creation.

## <sub><sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub></sub> ~/Sites

For storing your websites. Accessible on the network as /~username.

## <sub><sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub></sub> ~/Library

If you're not already aware, there's a ~/Library which is hidden, but does have a 'special icon' if you unhide it using `chflags nohidden ~/Library` or enable Show Library Folder in View Options.